# Plotting two variables as lines using ggplot2 on the one graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, aes

```
Year  Export Import
  <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
1 2000  79     32    
2 2001  86     34    
3 2002  87     32    
4 2003  87     32    
5 2004  98     34    
6 2005  107    37
```

How can I plot both export import on the same graph, with year on the x-axis, using ggplot2?

I'm sure this is very simple, but I can't find any examples out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
df <- data.frame(
        Year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L),
      Export = c(79L, 86L, 87L, 87L, 98L, 107L),
      Import = c(32L, 34L, 32L, 32L, 34L, 37L)
                     )

library(tidyverse)

df_l <- pivot_longer(df, cols = -Year)

ggplot(df_l, aes(Year, value, color = name)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>